# Routing in MVC Web Api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api

I want to get some data from Api in mvc.

this is client side

```
        public List<UserType> SearchUserType(string text)
    {

        HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:3852/api/Default1/" + text);
        wr.Method = "GET";

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse();
        Stream r_stream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader response_stream = new StreamReader(r_stream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8"));
        var s = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        return s.Deserialize<List<UserType>>(response_stream.ReadToEnd());
    }
```

I Receive `Text` from `textBox`.
and this is my Api

```
        public List<UserType> Get(string userTypeName)
    {
        return (from c in bl.Select() where c.UserTypeName.Contains(userTypeName) select c).ToList<UserType>();
    }
```

I think my routing is wrong .this is my routing in `RouteConfig.cs`.

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

What changes should I do on `RouteConfig.cs` to work correctly.
this is my `WebApiConfig.cs`class.

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: which version of web API are you using?

Comment: This is a `routeconfig.cs`, look for `WebApiConfig.cs` in `AppStart` folder, and check routing pattern.

Comment: @ Frebin Francis I think 2.2. I test [Routing] but it does not work.

Comment: @nimaSadeghpour can you please show me your WebApiConfig.cs class ?

Comment: @Frebin Francis I edited.

Comment: @nimaSadeghpour ok, you cannot call this method like you specified in your question.for this you need to specify the Get Method with Route attribute which is available in web API 2.2.

Comment: @Frebin Francis I added Route attribute `   [Route("api/default1/{usertypename}")]` but it didn't word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i change them and worked.
this is request

```
  HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:3852/api/default1/Get/" + text);
```

and this is `WebApiConfig`

```
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "SearchApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{usertypename}",
            defaults: new { usertypename = RouteParameter.Optional }

        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }

        );
    }
```